# How to generate the Klov report

Tags: java, extentreports

I have been trying the generate the report using Klov and am new to it. First, I have installed the MongoDb 3.2 and initialized it in the cmd then added the Klov 0.1.0 jar and Mongo-java-driver-3.4.3 jar in my project. When I run my project, the connection has been initialized and it generated the Htmlreporter but I couldn't able to find out the Klov report anywhere.

I have initialized the MongoDb in the cmd:
[image: I have initialized the MongoDb in the cmd]

Here the code:

```
htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter("TestReport.html");
    htmlReporter.setAppendExisting(true);
    klov = new KlovReporter();
    report = new ExtentReports();

    klov.initMongoDbConnection("localhost", 27017);

    klov.setProjectName("MyKlov");

    klov.setReportName("Build " + date.toString());

    klov.setKlovUrl("http://localhost");
    report.attachReporter(htmlReporter, klov);
    report.setSystemInfo("OS", "Windows");
    report.setSystemInfo("Host Name", "XXX");
    report.setSystemInfo("Environment", "QA");
    report.setSystemInfo("User Name", "XXXXXXX");

    htmlReporter.config().setChartVisibilityOnOpen(true);
    htmlReporter.config().setDocumentTitle(" Automation Testing");
    htmlReporter.config().setReportName("Automation Test Report");
    htmlReporter.config().setTestViewChartLocation(ChartLocation.TOP);
    htmlReporter.config().setTheme(Theme.STANDARD);

    logger = report.createTest("ROF");
```

After running the code, it shows some values in the cmd:
[image: After running the code, it shows some values in the cmd]

what're the actual steps to generate the Klov report?

Comment: Please do not link to raster images of text/code. Include the code in your question, within a properly formatted block.

Comment: Please go through the docs.  Usage does not change after you have attached klov.  You should see the server start at the Port defined in your application.properties:  default is localhost:80.  Link: 
 http://extentreports.com/docs/klov/

Comment: Did You actually start Klov server? Couldn't get from Your question. You  should start mongoDb and klov.jar, did You achive this, or the problem is the code itself?

Answer (score 2):

```
            extent = new ExtentReports();
            KlovReporter klovReporter = new KlovReporter();
            klovReporter.initMongoDbConnection("yourIPaddress", 27017);
            klovReporter.setProjectName("My project");
            klovReporter.setReportName("reportName");
            klovReporter.setKlovUrl("http://yourIPaddress");
            extent.attachReporter(klovReporter);
```

Start: 
 - MongoDB 3.2 cmd
 - Run Klov jar in cmd

Natigate using browser to: http://localhost or yourIPaddress.

Comment: You need Mongo 3.2 as stated above.